# iPhone : How to check device using MACRO?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I want to check whether the device is `iPhone` or `iPad` using the `macro`.

I have a file `Constant.h` where I have given values using `#define`.

Now, I want to check device using `#ifdef` `#endif`.

Follwing method can be possible only in the `.m` file.

But I have only one `.h` only.

```
- (BOOL) isPad{ 
   #ifdef UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM
        return (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad);
   #else
       return NO;
   #endif
}
```

So above method is not useful for me ?

Is there any way to do this ? Or any other way?

Comment: #ifdef UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM is broken in Xcode 6.3+ as it is no longer a preprocessor define

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't check it by macro, because macro is expanded during compilation. So you need to know   device type at compile time.

If you want to support both devices at runtime, you need to check device type and use appropriate set of constants.

Answer (score 5):

I have simple answer to this question.

```
#define isiPad (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad ? YES : NO)
```

This will returns 1 if device is iPad and 0 if device is iPod or iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

```
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED >= 30200
    UIDevice* thisDevice = [UIDevice currentDevice];
    if(thisDevice.userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
    {
    // etc.
    }
 #endif
```

Comment: this is not possible in .h file.